# Reading CSV files with Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file called `test.csv` like this:

```
id     name               quantity
 1     warehouse_name     4
```

I can read the name field like this:

```
require 'csv'
csv = CSV.read('test.csv', :headers=>true)
p csv['name']
```

Suppose I have 300 items on the `name` field, and I just want to grab unique names, because some of them repeat.

How can I tell if they already exist?

Comment: That's not a CSV format file, it's a space-separated value file, i.e. columnar. You can't use CSV to read it. CSV stands for "comma-separated-value", which don't exist separating your input fields so all text will be in the first field. Using your code and that input results in `csv['name']` returning `[nil, nil]`. Please read "[mcve]".

Comment: @the Tin Man Technically you are correct, but I thought it was pretty clear what he meant.

Comment: While it might be possible to guess, it's really important to remember that SO isn't about guessing. It's an online reference to help not only the person asking but those in the future who are searching for a similar solution to the same problem. When we "guess" we reduce accuracy and induce wobble. We might guess right, we might guess wrong, the OP might interpolate from our guess and get an answer but others in the future will find the results wander farther afield and reduce the usefulness. That's why SO requests detailed questions and answers, to avoid those problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of `csv['name']` will be an array of strings, which you can treat like any other array of strings.

```
>> array = csv['name']
=> ["Mark", "Betty", "Mark", "Jane", "Fred", "Jane"]
>> array.uniq
=> ["Mark", "Betty", "Jane", "Fred"]
```

Refer to the docs for [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) and [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) for much more information.

Comment: If you try it with the OPs sample data and code `csv['name']` will not return names.